# Normalizing a blowup in a finite regular cover of the original surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite flat morphism of integral projective surfaces over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic 0. Assume $X$ is regular and $Y$ is normal. Let $\tilde{Y}\rightarrow Y$ be a proper birational morphism with $\tilde{Y}$ regular. Is the normalization of $\tilde{Y}$ inside (the function field of) $X$ regular?

If this is not true in general, then is it true if one also assumes some combination of the following:

1. The singularities of $Y$ are "mild" (for some notion of mild),
2. $\tilde{Y}$ is a minimal desingularization of $Y$,
3. $\tilde{Y}$ is general type.